# Installing yum packages on airgapped (offline) CentOS 6 system

Tags: centos, centos6, yum, repository, offline-files

I have a CentOS 6 system which, for security reasons, is airgapped. It may have never been connected to the internet, and if it has, it hasn't been updated in a long time.

I want to put all the .rpm packages on a drive so that they can be installed offline without querying the internet. However, the issue I am running into on my test VM is that `yum` keeps hanging and trying to update from an online repository, even though the local path is specified.

Also, is there a way to easily grab a package and *all dependencies* for that package using `yum-utils`/`yumdownloader`? At the moment, it still misses some dependencies (e.g. when I pull the gcc-c++ rpm, it'll grab `cpp` and `gcc` but it won't pull `cloog-ppl`, `mpfr` or `ppl`)

I have already tried a [solution like this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345351/installing-rpm-with-dependencies-offline), but I cannot assume there will already be a dependency tree, or that `yum` will be up to date.

On a fresh install of the docker image, the first time I try to run yum (with internet disabled), I get
`Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: base. Please verify its path and try again`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are concerned about compatibility between installed release and latest stable, you may want to determine your centos version in `/etc/redhat-release` and to use packages from http://vault.centos.org/, however bear in mind that they won't contain any security updates or bug fixes.

To download packages - use official redhat instrucions: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/10154

```
yum install yum-plugin-downloadonly
yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=<directory> <package>
```

or

```
yum install yum-utils
yumdownloader --resolve
```

You may also look at replicating yum history on vm where you want to download rpms to with techniques from this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83115

> The easiest way, and it's worked for a long time is:
>
> ```
> yum-debug-dump => gives file.
> yum-debug-restore <file-from-debug-dump>
> ```
>
> ...which works much like the get/set selections dpkg command, AIUI. Also note that if you are replaying history you can use:
>
> ```
> yum history addon-info last saved_tx => gives file
> yum load-tx <file-from-addon-info>
> ```
>
> ...instead of having to parse it yourself.

**Edit:**

To install all rpms from directory, `cd` to it and simply use
`rpm -ivh *.rpm` if you want to install them, or `rpm -Uvh *.rpm` if some downloaded files are newer than already present ones, and you are okay with updating them.

Comment: Ok, this is useful for downloading, but do you have any insight on how to deal with an out-of-date yum which will not install from a file without checking dependencies from an internet repo?

Comment: Do you really need yum for that? You can simply install all the downloaded rpms with `rpm`

Comment: updated answer with rpm part

Comment: Ok, that's really weird. Yesterday, when I ran --downloadonly, it didn't pull down the dependencies. Today, on a fresh docker session, it worked fine.

I think `rpm` will work for my purposes. Since the system is offline, I can't imagine them using `yum` at all. It just refuses to work right without an internet connection, or some seriously gross hacks.

Comment: Alright it seems that `rpm` is in fact the best answer. Yeah it makes `yum` db get a little grumpy, but if they are offline, they can't be using yum anyways, so it should work out. Since I can't guarantee that the cache is up to date, rpm is the safest solution.

Comment: How can I download the rpm for centos 6.x in a centos7.* system?

Answer (score 1):

edit: NOPE, nothing is every this easy. Still getting this error on a fresh stack: 
`Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: base. Please verify its path and try again`

If I let yum access the internet for just long enough to configure itself, the following works:

First I was able to pull down all the dependency packages with calls to

`yum install -y --downloadonly --downloaddir=$pkgdir <package>`

and

`yum reinstall -y --downloadonly --downloaddir=$pkgdir <package>`

to force any already installed packages to pull their `.rpm` and dependencies. Then, once I had procured my tarball of packages, I put that on a fresh system.

First, I ran `sed -i 's/enabled=1/enabled=0/' '/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/fastestmirror.conf'` to disable the fastmirror plugin.

Then, I was able to install all the packages I needed by cd'ing into the directory with the packages, then carefully calling

`yum install --disablerepo=\* packag*`

in the order required by the dependencies. So that looked kinda like

```
yum install --disablerepo=\* epel*
yum install --disablerepo=\* ius*
yum install --disablerepo=\* libstd*
yum install --disablerepo=\* mpfr*
yum install --disablerepo=\* cpp*
yum install --disablerepo=\* libgcc*
yum install --disablerepo=\* libgomp*
yum install --disablerepo=\* libg*
yum install --disablerepo=\* ppl*
yum install --disablerepo=\* cloog*
yum install --disablerepo=\* gcc*
yum install --disablerepo=\* atlas*
yum install --disablerepo=\* python*
```

And voila! I was able to run python3.5 on a fully airgapped system.